# Can congruence or similarity be used to find the length of a triangle when some of its sides have odds proportionality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

In my book there is this problem but I don't know if congruence or similarity can be used as means to solve it.

The problem is as follows:

> A CTV broadcasting tower is resting atop a square flat base in the
>   highest hill of Taipei. The tower is supported by five cables which
>   are held tight to the ground by four retention screws labeled
>   $\textrm{A}$, $\textrm{C}$, $\textrm{D}$, $\textrm{E}$, $\textrm{F}$
>   as indicated in the picture. The radio technician notices that the
>   length between $\textrm{HC = 3 feet}$, meanwhile $3AB=5BC$ and $m\angle ABH= 3m \angle HBC$
>   From this information find the distance between $\textrm{H}$ and
>   $\textrm{A}$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given on my book are:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{13 feet}\\
2.&\textrm{11 feet}\\
3.&\textrm{9 feet}\\
4.&\textrm{10 feet}\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do is shown in the figure from below.

[image: Sketch of the attempted solution]

But other than just putting what is stated in the problem I could not reach any further in my observations. I tried hardly to imagine different ways to arrange the triangles in a manner that they could be used as congruence (from which I noticed one). But other than that I coudn't find more.

Therefore can somebody help me to find the answer **using** mainly simple **euclidean geometry**?. i.e using constructions and tying it with similarity or congruence or something like this? This is what basically gets me stuck.

Although I welcome an answer using plane trigonometry this question was supposedly been able to be solved without requiring trig or any advanced math tools, hence I hope somebody could help me with a trig free approach.

Comment: I think you mean $\angle ABH = 3\angle HBC$, not $\angle ABC$

Comment: @Quanto Yes this was a mistake from my side I corrected it in the rewording of the question.

Comment: great. then answer should work

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw the line BD such that $\angle DBH = \angle CBH$. Then, $DH = HC = 3$ feet. Apply the sine rule to triangles BAD and BDC,

$$\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{\sin(180-\beta)} = \frac{AH - 3}{AB},\>\>\>\>\>
\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{\sin\beta} = \frac{6}{BC}$$

Use the fact $\sin(180-\beta)=\sin\beta$ to get
$$\frac{AH-3}{6}=\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac 53$$

which yields $AH = 13 \>\text{feet}$.

Comment: If you look closely to what I did I was not that far from your route (omiting the fact that I was not close to use trig). Can this question be solved without requiring it?. Btw i'm stuck at trying to **see** how did you come up with a relationship for $AB$. Can you split the equality in different lines to understand it better to know which came from where?. (sorry I'm slow with this). Perhaps do you refer to $\frac{AB}{\sin\left(180-\beta\right)}$? otherwise I still don't get it.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - Yeah, you approach resembles that in the answer. I split the equations as you requested.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I believed that using solely the angle bisector teorem would suffice to solve this problem. At first looking the proof via trig confused me a bit, but once I noticed the "catch" with $\left(180-\beta\right)$ made me understood.